# Filtering Rows in SQL using conditions

Tags: plsqldeveloper

```
clm_id  adj_no  ln_no   AMT code    name    add
a       0       1       5   2       e       22
a       0       2       2   2       e       22
a       0       3       0   2       e       22


clm_id  adj_no  ln_no   AMT code    name    add
b       1       1       0   2       e       22
b       1       2       0   2       e       22
b       1       3       0   2       e       22
```

1.i have the above two sets of records for ID  in source table.
2. now, i have to sum the AMT column based on  clm_id , adj_no, for first set of records, the sum(AMT) will be 7, so i want all this records to be pulled in my query
3. now, i have to sum the AMT column based on  clm_id , adj_no, for SEcond set of records, the sum(AMT) will be 0, so i want all this records not to be pulled in my query

basically if AMT sum is greater than 0 , i want to pull all the records.the resulting record should have the AMT column as in Source(not the sum(AMT) )

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL? Or even Oracle? Please choose the tags carefully.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT clm_id, adj_no, SUM(AMT) AS AMT_SUM 
  FROM source_table 
 GROUP BY clm_id, adj_no 
 HAVING AMT_SUM > 0
```

Comment: A `WHERE amt > 0` would have the same effect and may be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, if the AMT never be a negative value.

Comment: Yes, MySQL supports the having statement.

Comment: hi Thanks for your reply, i am working in PLSQL developer, if i use the above query i am getting two rows from source,

clm_id  adj_no  ln_no   AMT code    name    add
a       0       1       5   2       e       22
a       0       2       2   2       e       22

not the third row which has AMT 0

a       0       3       0   2       e       22

i need this row, because the total amt (3 records is not zero)

Comment: If you using my code above, it should have two rows, each have only three columns:clm_id, adj_no, AMT_SUM.